# How to pass model value as a string in arguments in ng-init

Tags: angularjs

hi how can send the model value is string

ng-init='function(profileData.nonCfci["DnpDSTTimeOffset"])'

how to send profileData.nonCfci["DnpDSTTimeOffset"] as string

Comment: You should not use ng-init in the first place. But your question is very unclear.

Comment: agree with @JBNizet, `ng-init` has *very specific* cases it was designed for;  calling a function on init is not one of them.  use a controller instead.